# progress bar on taskbar icon using winforms .net 6 vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, winforms-interop

I am having a hard time finding a solution to display the status of a progressbar on the taskbar icon on Windows 10/11. Do you have suggestions.
I use Winforms with VB.Net .Net 6.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

thanks to all the same, I solved it like this:

installed package NuGet: "Microsoft-WindowsAPICodePack-Core" by rpastric, contre, dahall

```
'Imports
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Taskbar

        Dim stato_istanza = TaskbarProgressBarState.Normal
        Dim istanza = TaskbarManager.Instance
        istanza.SetProgressState(stato_istanza)
        istanza.SetProgressValue(value, valuemax)
```

All tested and working with Winforms VB.Net with .Net 6.0 and Visual Studio 2022

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure as it's not something that I've done myself but I think that you can use the [Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts/) package for that. I believe that that is what replaced the [WindowsAPICodePack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack/) package.

Comment: It looks more like a comment than an answer. I'd suggest you improve it by adding more explanation and code example on how to do it, or post it as a comment.